# Should you always do a COUNT(*) before a SELECT * to determine if there are any rows?

Tags: mysql, performance, select, count, row

In MySQL, is it generally a good idea to always do a `COUNT(*)` first to determine if you should do a SELECT * to actually fetch the rows, or is it better to just do the `SELECT *` directly and then check if it returned any rows?

Comment: It depends what your goal is...

Comment: Doing a count(*) is a useless exercise if you're going to do a select afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you lock the table/s in question, doing a `select count(*)` is useless. Consider:

Process 1:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T;
```

Process 2:

```
INSERT INTO T
```

Process 1:

```
...now doing something based on the obsolete count retrieved before...
```

Of course, locking a table is not a very good idea in a server environment.

Comment: +1. This is the only answer that mentions reading a value that is usually obsolete a few moments after.

Comment: transaction should suffice if engine permits, not necessarily locking.

Comment: @Michael Krelin Just suppose that I need to insert a row if and only if the table is empty. If I go with the `select count(*)` I need to block all inserts (BTW best option in that case, and most others, is to add some EXISTS filter to the WHERE clause of the 2nd statement, and then use the affected rows output to know if the operation succeded).

Comment: Well, this logic requires locking this way or another, I was referring to the case of your data just being obsolete for the purpose of future retrieval (we were talking about doing select count before doing select, remember?).

Comment: @Michael Krelin - hacker Unless you set `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level (and that has implications on performance / program logic, so you cannot just "set the parameter"), you will not get consistent reads from two consecutive `SELECT` even inside the same transaction.

Comment: Isn't there a repeatable read in mysql? As for implications, one should definitely go for it if one needs it.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Phantom_reads. Aboy MySQL, either you are using multiversion concurrency and `REPETEABLE READ` is effectively a synonym for `SERIALIZABLE`, or you use the old, lock-based engine and then you most probably have phantom reads.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you need the number, but in particular in `mysql` there's a `calc_found_rows`, IIRC. Look up the docs.

Comment: No need unless you're `LIMIT`ing the query. `num_rows()` works fine.

Comment: @ceejayoz, yes, I assumed the case of pagination or similar.

Answer (score 1):

always the `SELECT [field1, field2 | *] FROM....  The SELECT COUNT(*)` will just bloat your code, add additional transport and data overhead and generally be unmaintainable.

Answer (score 0):

The form is 2 queries, the latter is 1 query. Each query needs to talk with the database server. Do the math.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as in many of this kind questions - "it depends". What you shouldn't do is performing those two queries when you do not have an index on a table. In general, performing just COUNT is a waste of IO time, so if if this operation will help you to save some time spent on IO in MOST cases, than it might be an option.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases some db driver implementations may not return the count of actually selected rows for select statement that returns records itself. The 'count(*)' issued beforehand is useful when you need to know the precise size of resulting recordset before you select actual data.